# MS Access VBA Unbound field Date issue

Tags: vba, date

I have the following unbound fields in a form:

txtCBDate - format "Medium Date" - My PC localization settings for date: "dd/mm/yyyy"
    txtCBRemarks.

In VBA, for cmdSAVE_Click event, I have the following code:

```
Dim myDate as Date
Dim myRemarks as String

myDate = txtCBDate.Value
myRemarks = txtCBRemarks.Value

Sql = insert into CB (CBDate, CBRemarks) values (myDate, myRemarks)

db.Execute(SQL)
```

The values are inserted into the table, CB.  However, the inserted date is a wrong date, i.e., not the date entered by me in the form.  e.g., if I entered "20-02-2016", the date saved in the database is "11-07-1894".  The other dates entered are also saved correspondingly with reference to the year 1894.

I tried "Compact and Repair Database" as well as deleting the textbox and re-designing the form, but to no avail.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you debugged to see the values in your variables?

Comment: Yes, I have debugged the variable value and find that the value of 'myDate' shows '20-02-2016' in the watch window.  However, the value written to the table is '11-07-1894'.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are different formats in your machine's date and time settings. For example, on my machine, short date is dd/MM/yyyy and long date is dd MMMM yyyy (I don't seem to have a medium date format visible in my settings).

I would suggest trying changing the format of the text box to short date, on the assumption that the date format in your settings is actually your short date format opposed to your medium date format.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, and changed the date format to short date.  But, the result is the same error value.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging the value of variable 'myDate', as suggested by Mark, I found that in the Insert statement, myDate was not enclosed in single quotes.

Sql = insert into CB (CBDate, CBRemarks) values (' " & myDate & " ', & " ' myRemarks & " ')

I only had the double quotes "" enclosing the variables.  After enclosing the variables in single quotes as well, the issue got resolved.
I am sorry that I did not make a mention regarding the single/double quotes in my earlier post.  Thanks in particular to Mark C, and, also to UberDoodles for their suggestions.

Comment: Glad you figured it out